# How to add some new records to a One2many field in an onchange method in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to modify an *One2many* field through an *onchange* method. What I need is to add some records but preserve some of the existing ones before the *onchange* computation.

To be more accurate, I have a field named `tax_line_ids`. This field stores taxes. Taxes have a field named `manual`, a `Boolean`.

So each time the field `my_field` changes, I need to add new taxes to the *One2many* field `tax_line_ids`, but I need to preserve the old ones which have `manual` set to *True*.

**Attempt A**

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def onchange_my_field(self):
    new_tax_lines = []
    tax_line_ids = self.tax_line_ids.filtered(
        lambda r: r.manual).ids
    # get_taxes_values returns a list of dictionaries with values
    tax_grouped = self.get_taxes_values()
    for tax in tax_grouped.values():
        new_tax = self.env['account.invoice.tax'].create(tax)
        tax_line_ids.append(new_tax.id)
    self.tax_line_ids = [(6, 0, tax_line_ids)]
```

***Problem***

The *onchange* method works fine, but when I click on *Save* button, the `tax_line_ids` records introduced by my *onchange* method disappear (`tax_line_ids` is not a readonly field).

**Attempt B**

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def onchange_my_field(self):
    new_tax_lines = []
    manual_tax_lines = self.tax_line_ids.filtered(
        lambda r: r.manual)
    for manual_tax_line in manual_tax_lines:
        new_tax_lines.append(manual_tax_line.sudo().read()[0])
    tax_grouped = self.get_taxes_values()
    for tax in tax_grouped.values():
        new_tax_lines.append((0, 0, tax))
    self.tax_line_ids = new_tax_lines
```

***Problem***

The *onchange* method works fine the first time, even if I click on *Save* button (records does not dissapear), but if I modify `my_field` a second time before saving, I got a security access error (I am working with the admin):

> (Document type: account.invoice.tax, Operación: read)

This is the reason why I added `sudo()` before the `read()`, just in case, but the error still remains.

**Conclusion**

So, in my *onchange* method, how can I add new records to the *One2many* field preserving some of the existing ones?

Comment: Attempt A shouldn't work because `create` isn't working in an onchange environment. I worked on something like that for days, but i'm not sure if i had a working solution in the end. Odoo 10 is getting old by now :-/

Comment: Ok, solution A out, but B... the [(0, 0, values)] system works in onchange. The [(4, ID)] system too. How to combine both? If they cannot be combined, why I get a security error with `read` method? Do you have any idea?

Comment: No not really, the access error is very weird, because you're using `sudo` already. Maybe there is another error being masked by this wrong error message?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, but not the solution. The `read()` method gives the error only when the manual tax has not been saved yet. So, when I trigger the onchange I preserve a manual tax copying its values with `read()` and creating it again with `(0, 0, vals)`, but after that, if I trigger the onchange again, that manual tax does not have an ID, so I cannot call `read()`. How could I get its values?

Comment: I would debug and look what odoo is giving you in both situations. There has to be a solution and it will be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def onchange_my_field(self):
    tax_line_ids = self.tax_line_ids.filtered(
        lambda r: r.manual).ids
    # get_taxes_values returns a list of dictionaries with values
    tax_grouped = self.get_taxes_values()
    new_tax_datas = []
    for tax in tax_grouped.values():
        new_tax_datas.append(tax)
    self.tax_line_ids = [
        (4, tl_id) for tl_id in tax_line_ids,
        (0, 0, td) for td in new_tax_datas]
```

OR

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def onchange_my_field(self):
    new_tax_lines = []
    tax_lines = self.tax_line_ids.filtered(
        lambda r: r.manual)
    # get_taxes_values returns a list of dictionaries with values
    tax_grouped = self.get_taxes_values()
    for tax in tax_grouped.values():
        new_tax = self.env['account.invoice.tax'].create(tax)
        tax_lines += new_tax
    self.tax_line_ids = [(6, 0, tax_lines.ids)]
```

Comment: Hi @OpenCode, thank you for answering. The second solution does the same as my first attempt. It seems to work ok until I click on *Save* button, when records disappear (because of what @CZoellner comments in the question). The first solution gives a syntax error, but the idea was good, I tried to pass a list combining `(4, ID)` with `(0, 0, values)`. But the result is the following error: `ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'generator'`.

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def onchange_my_field(self):
    account_invoice_tax = self.env['account.invoice.tax']
    for invoice in self:
        invoice._cr.execute("DELETE FROM account_invoice_tax WHERE invoice_id=%s AND manual is False", (invoice.id,))
        if invoice._cr.rowcount:
            invoice.invalidate_cache()
        tax_grouped = invoice.get_taxes_values()

        # Create new tax lines
        for tax in tax_grouped.values():
            account_invoice_tax.create(tax)
```

I just tried existing method.

Comment: Hi @Vishnu, thank you for answering. That code does not work in an `onchange` method. It gives you the error `ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'NewId'`.

Answer (score -1):

forvas

Try to do this,
**return {'value': {'your_one2many_field' : list_of_ids}}**

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe in more detail why this should work? And why use the old API style coding, it won't be helpful for Odoo 11 and up.

Comment: @CZoellner Yes, Of Course, I'll explain before that have ever properly read the question has been asked? I don't think so. Firstly this was the questioning about the odoo-10 version and yes it can be used in that version to store the data in one2many fields.odoo 10 version has not a much effective way to clear your cache where sometime you won't get the result[that doesn't save your changes]. So this could be the way to archive this.